# how to get match, location, history props in react router DOM 5 using component class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

This question is specifically for `react-router-dom` version 5.

Here's my `App` component following the structures of the [quick start guide](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ProductDetails from "./components/productDetails";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/products/:id">
          <ProductDetails />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

And here's my `productDetails.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ProductDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <h1>Product Details - {this.props.match.params.id}</h1>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductDetails;
```

which
How to get the `this.props.match.params.id` in class component way, not function way.
Also I found that the corresponding props empty:
[image]

but, those values are in `Router.Provider`:
[image]

So, how to get all the `Route` component's props from it's children using class?

Comment: Did you check it using the withRoute HOC? I believe that gives your component access to these params

Comment: Almost. It's [`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `withRouter` HOC to your class component then you will have access to the this.props.match.params

import it from react-router

`import { withRouter } from "react-router";`

Then wrap your component with it like this

`export default withRouter(ProductDetails);`